# How Whatsapp attachment's window can override keyboard?

Tags: android

I'm working on a similiar problem developing my chat and I was checking on how whatsapp solves it to get an idea to work on it.

On mobile and inside a conversation, when your keyboard is up on the screen and you click on attachments, the attachments window overrides the keboard like the image below. It also look likes the activity under it freezes ( you can look at the  slash "|" on the EditText, it seems that is freeze ).

I was wondering how WP could override the keyboard and why it looks like the activity under it is freezing, thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can use BottomSheetDialog to do something like this : example : http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/modal-bottom-sheet-with-material-design.html

Comment: wow nice man, seems to be the correct answer!! Really thx man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]      /**Use the below code Snipet without using any library**/

```
   action_attach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog();
        }
    });


  private void openDialog() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // inflate the custom popup layout
    final View inflatedView;

    inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_options_menu, null, false);

    LinearLayout layoutGallery;
   layoutGallery = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.layoutGallery);
    layoutGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FloatingView.dismissWindow();
        }
    });

    FloatingView.onShowPopup(this, inflatedView);
  }



 /**Sample Layout for Pop Up window ie: custom_dialog_options_menu
    and change layout according to your choice***/


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingTop="82dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutGallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_attach_icon_selector"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Gallery"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#4d4747"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPhoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_attach_icon_selector"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Camera"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#4d4747"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutVideo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/video_attach_icon_selector"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Video"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#4d4747"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


/**FloatingView Class**/

public class FloatingView
{
/* Floating view is used to display a custom view for attachments in the chat screen */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

private static PopupWindow popWindow;

private FloatingView() {
}


public static void onShowPopup(Activity activity, View inflatedView) {

    // get device size
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    // fill the data to the list items
    // set height depends on the device size
    popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            true);
    // set a background drawable with rounders corners
    popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.comment_popup_bg));
    // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
    popWindow.setFocusable(true);
    // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
    popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    popWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at
    // bottom ie,

    popWindow.showAtLocation(activity.getCurrentFocus(), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,
            0);
}

public static void dismissWindow() {

    popWindow.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: This is dismissing the keypad and then showing the PopUp Window. How to show it over the keypad like WhatsApp? Thanks!